# Mongoose how to push an element to a schema of array of arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want a schema with an array containing arrays so I have the following schema defined:

```
runGroupEntries: [
        [
            {
                type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User',
                require: true
            }
        ]
    ]
```

My intention is to have

```
runGroupEntries[['userId1', 'userId2', 'userId3'], ['userId4', 'userId5', 'userId6], ...]
```

I initialized the schema using:

```
for (let i = 0; i < numGroups; ++i) {
    event.runGroupEntries.push(undefined);
}
```

In MongoDB Atlas, it shows:
[initialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnHaE.png)

It looks fine to me.
The way I insert element is

```
event.runGroupEntries[runGroup].push(userId);
```

In this example, runGroup is 0. I was expecting to see

```
runGroupEntries: [ [ null, "userId" ], [ null ], [ null ], [ null ], [ null ] ]
```

but the actual result is:

```
runGroupEntries: [ [ null, [Array] ], [ null ], [ null ], [ null ], [ null ] ],
```

[1st push result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Mfd.png)

Then I tried to push another userId to event.runGroupEntries[0]. Interestingly, previous array now becomes "userId" but the new element been pushed still shows an array.

```
runGroupEntries: [
    [ null, 5f5c1d95e4f678ce190d5624, [Array] ],
```

[2nd push result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpblt.png)

I am really clueless why the pushed element became an array.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a bug in Mongoose. It's fixed now https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9429